# Which one is correct option for significant correlation meaning

Tags: statistics, regression, correlation

a significant correlation is one which

a) indicates a valid difference

b) is especially meaningful

c) can be generalized to the population

d) does not deviate from zero

Is it correct d) ?

Comment: @Chinny84 ,I thought option d) , because null hypothesis : rho = 0 (no relationship) , its rejected ...so there is relationship between two variables, so option d)??

Comment: e4e5 - Thank you for providing a possible answer, I was just trying to get you to put down a rationale reason and then we can update if incorrect. Then you get more out of it than me just answering :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a significant correlation we mean that the observed correlation in the sample is not due to chance, at that level of significance. The observed correlation in the sample is a representative of the correlation in the population. In other words, the correlation observed in the sample can be generalized to the population. Option (c) is correct.